# HTML/SCSS how to use grid to center generated objects while align left

Tags: html, sass, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I have some components that is generated by a for-loop based on number of objects from the server, that is going to be displayed on frontend,

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="component">
        <div class="row card">
         <app-component class="list-group-item col" [User]="comp.user"
                        [title]="comp.title"
                        *ngFor="let comp of component"></app-component>
       </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

I want the components to be aligned in the middle while the last row will align left. The current situation is that the components is align center, when I want the last row of components to align left.

[How our current html looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAgM4.png)

The margins on each side remain equal related to number of components.

The component has a fixed size, and as the screen is bigger (or adjusted) it will fit more component in each row while the gap between the components expands.

[How it looks like when the screen adjust to bigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYFaY.png)

As in the image there is even components, but if there were 1 more component it would be placed in the center of a third row. In that case, I want the last component to be placed left in a third row.

this is our current scss file:

```
.component {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    > .card {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        > app-component {
            margin-top: 2rem;
            margin-right: 3rem;
        }
    }
}
```

The main problem is that all the component is generated by a for-loop based on how many object i get from server. therefor i cant customize each component for them self

Comment: Have you tried `text-align: left;` on the parent element of the `.component` divs?

Comment: yes i have, nothing happend or changed.

Comment: can you post the .css you have for the container surrounding the .component ?

Comment: the container around the .component is bootstrap, .container-fluid.  I added it to the description,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using grid system of bootstraps 4, it can define how many columns an element in HTML will use based on the screen size and resolved my problem.

```
<div class="container root">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 card"
      *ngFor="let comp of component>
      <app-component [user]="comp.user"
                     [title]="comp.title"></app-component>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The bootstrap class take based on the size of the screen and change classes, you can read more about it at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I quite undetsand well your needs.
Either look at flexboxes : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Or why don't you use BS4 columns grid ???

Furthermore, you mix components and grid classes : Only col can be children of rows.

```
<div class="component">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card">
      CARD CONTENT GOES HERE
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Tell us more about your research.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenient, it was really hard to explain my situation. I have tried to use BS4 columns grid too with no result. it gave approximate the same as the images i have put in.